# Want to insert data with the help of composite key in my CouchBase but facing this problem

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Want to have a composite key of a combination of student `name` and his `birthdate`.

Here is my query:

```
Insert into TestBucket(Key,value)
values(
["Name":"Aman",  "birthdate":"12/04/1995"],
"English":[
{
  "midterm": 34,
  "endterm": 67
}
],
"Maths":
[
{
  "midterm": 20,
  "endterm": 40
}
],
"Computer":
[
  {
    "midterm": 48,
    "endterm": 90
  }
]
)
```

And here is the error that i got:

```
error "code": 3000
"msg": "syntax error - at :",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change two things. First, your key should be a string. Assemble it however you want from the information available. Second, the document you are inserting should be a JSON object.

Here's an example that works:

```
insert into bucket1(key,value)
values("Aman--12/04/1995",
    {
        "English":[{ "midterm": 34, "endterm": 67 }],
        "Maths":[{ "midterm": 20, "endterm": 40 }],
        "Computer":[{ "midterm": 48, "endterm": 90 }]
    })
```